# Inserting row and deleting row simultaneously. UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a `UITableView` that represents a video library. The datasource of the library is a `NSMutableDictionary` that contains a `NSMutableArray` for each of its keys. Each of the Arrays contains an Array with all the info for each value.

`NSMutableDictionary` -> Foreach Key a `NSMutableArray` that contains -> `NSMutableArrays`.

`tableSectionData`is my datasource.

I have been trying to insert a row on the first section and delete another row in another section. This is the code I am using:

**EDIT** This is the new attempt. I first update the datasource and then add and delete the corresponding rows that are indexed with my dataSource.

```
[mainTableView beginUpdates];
    NSMutableDictionary *clone = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] 
                          initWithDictionary:self.tableSectionData copyItems:YES];
    for (NSString *key in [clone allKeys]) {
        if([key isEqualToString:@"Videos available for download"]) {
            for (NSArray *videoArray in [clone objectForKey:key]) {
                if ([[videoArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:helper.videoName]) {
                    [[self.tableSectionData objectForKey:@"Downloaded videos"] 
                                               addObject:videoArray];
                    NSUInteger insertIndex = [[self.tableSectionData 
                                               objectForKey:@"Downloaded videos"] 
                                                        indexOfObject:videoArray];
                    NSIndexPath *pathToInsert = [NSIndexPath 
                                         indexPathForRow:insertIndex inSection:0];
                    NSArray *indexesToAddition = [NSArray 
                                                    arrayWithObject:pathToInsert];
                    [mainTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexesToAddition 
                                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    [[self.tableSectionData 
          objectForKey:@"Videos available for download"] removeObject:videoArray];
                    NSUInteger deleteIndex = [[self.tableSectionData 
         objectForKey:@"Videos available for download"] indexOfObject:videoArray];
                    NSIndexPath *pathToDelete = [NSIndexPath 
                                         indexPathForRow:deleteIndex inSection:1];
                    NSArray *indexesToDeletion = [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                                                    pathToDelete];
                    [mainTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexesToDeletion 
                                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

                }
            }
        }
    }
    [mainTableView endUpdates];
```

I thought this would work since I have to first delete a row if I want to insert one (in the case I want to do both.)

The specific error is the following:

```
'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

I know what the error says, that I don't have a corresponding number of rows on the section however I don't see my mistake on the code and I logged the datasource and it corresponds to the desired result.

Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 14):

You have to do all updates inside begin/end updates methods. It's valid always if you have more than one UITableView update.

And don't forget update dataSource before endUpdates called!

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

    // do your staff here, like:
[self.tableView inserRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

your mistake here - is you are using different begin/end updates sections in your code sample

Comment: As on the comments of the code I already state that I already tried this that's why I tried doing it on separate sections. So this isn't the problem. Plus, the insertRowsAtIndexPaths HAS to be AFTER the deleteRowsAtIndexPaths or it won't work according to the documentation and to the tests I have already made. Thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Where is your **dataSource**?

**before delete**

```
[dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:nIndexDelete];
[mainTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexesToDeletion 
                                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

**before add**

```
[dataSource inserObject:object atIndex:nIndexAdd];
[mainTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexesToAddition 
                                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I already did this (or most likely I am doing it wrong) Look at the first for where I iterate through the clone of my dataSource. My dataSource is tableSectionData, there I add and remove the objects in question. What I am trying to do is transferring one row of a section to another section. I don't see the mistake in my code...

Comment: may i know what code you use in method **numberOfSectionsInTableView:** and **tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:** ?

Comment: I know those parts of the UITableViewDelegate are correct it is more of an issue of the order in which the updates are being called. the reloadData method worked for me but I still don't understand why the insert and delete don't work. Look at the updated question.

Comment: why not put all the index you want to delete into one indexToDeleteArray and index to insert into indexToInsertArray? I don't think it's good idea to loop at delete and insert Row.  Btw, trace also insertIndex and deleteIndex to see whether they are the index you wanna delete

Answer (score -3):

I think you need to reload UITableView every time you insert or delete rows with returning exact number of rows in numberOfRowsInSection ...

Comment: I already tried this but didn't work. I will stick to the begin and end updates!