# iOS: Hierarchical List in UITableView or UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

iOS beginner - I'm trying to implement a hierarchical list that is displayed in one view. (I would like to reserve the drill-down functionality to edit each item.) Is a UITableView or UICollectionView (or something else) most appropriate for this? [See link for example from Todoist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBJpm.jpg), that's basically what I'm shooting for.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` is appropriate for doing this. You can create different cells for the different indentation levels. When selecting a cell you can insert/delete cells from the `UITableView` to keep the drill-down functionality. See this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14959373/6232045

Comment: You do not need different kinds of cells for the indentation. Every cell can be the same type. Simply set the `indentationLevel` property as needed.